# how to print new line in elementtree's Element().text

Tags: python, elementtree

I have this in my Element object's .text

```
e = ET.Element('p')
e.text = "hello <br> world"
e.write("a.html")
```

doesn't seem to work as expected.
it converts the angel brackets to `&lt`; 
any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tail` attribute, I haven't tested it but it should work as you expected:

```
e = ET.Element('p')
# you set the text to hello first
e.text = "hello "
# and you set a subelement with br, which is what you want
br = ET.SubElement(e, 'br')
# then using tail to append the text after br
br.tail = ' world'

...
```

Hope this helps.